# Use of Kendo observable binding in Kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-observable

I am using Kendo observable object to bind the Kendo ui grid. When  adding/editing the values in the data source it is reflecting in the grid as well as the observable array. When using load button and explicitly adding values to the Kendo observable is not reflecting in the grid.

Here is sample working code.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@bijum/ASoTu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works:

http://dojo.telerik.com/IVuko

I made the following changes:

- bound the Grid to the `personDataArray` ObservableObject, and not to just a field of the ObservableObject
- set `schema.data` to point to the `data` field of the `personDataArray`.
- called `dataSource.read()` when setting new data to the `personDataArray`

I think the last step should not be needed, but not sure.

Comment: Thanks dimodi. That helps